# What is "V4+agent" in IIS logs?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-10

I'm seeing log entries in IIS's log files such as the following. Not sure where they are coming from, but the user agent is "V4+agent".

> 2019-08-04 22:28:45 127.0.0.1 GET /api/passphrase - 443 - 127.0.0.1 V4+agent/1.0 - 404 0 2 0
>   2019-08-04 22:28:45 127.0.0.1 GET /api/license/timestamp/abc123abc123abc123 - 443 - 127.0.0.1 V4+agent/1.0 - 404 0 2 15

Comment: Seems to come from 127.0.0.1, it's the server himself... Something is running on the server and create these requests.

Comment: Yes, indeed ... just not sure what ...